# Why is the web page being requested twice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, browser, request

Notice in the picture that the top two records are identical except for the timings and the "Cause" on the first line is document whereas it's img on the second line. I've never seen this before where the entire page is requested twice and don't understand how "img" could be the cause for requesting the web page.

Can anyone give me an idea where to start looking for what may be causing this (I don't see anything about any images in my site that would seem to be related?)

[image: Network Activity]

Answer (score 0):

I found it. There was an image that was dynamically loaded, and so the developer set the src as "#" which was causing it to request the web page again. I found in another answer the best way to resolve this issue is to instead set the src to "//:0". The double slash sets it to current protocol so you don't get insecure warning, and port 0 is an invalid port so it won't actually make a request.